No connection to KRFB system remotely?
I am just so lost trying to get a secure desktop sharing working with KRFB. I keep following tutorial after tutorial and nothing works. I am however successfully able to connect locally right away using ssvnc-viewer with KRFB. Plus, all the self-help tutorials on the Internet don't ever mention port forwarding on the router for remote Desktop Sharing. This is very confusing.
I installed KRFB (server) and installed and tried clients (tightvnc, tigervnc, ssvnc-viewer). They simply don't ever connect.
All I ever get is socket refused connection error.
So, can someone please give me a step by step guide on setting up a remote desktop sharing on Linux (pcLinuxOS) using KRFB as the server?
